# SWT test if browser is supported

Tags: java, swt

Is there a way to test if `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` is supported on a system without actually initializing it and catching an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of eclipse 3.6.2, the only known method of checking `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` support is to initialize it and check for exception.